# How does guerrillabeat.com make bg video autoplay from mobile

Tags: android, ios, video, background

I am trying to do a website with a bg video and I want it to autoplay from mobile devices. I found this site http://guerrillabeat.com, but I can not replicate/figure out how they do it.

Kind Regards,

Kevin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to look at html5 canvas. Or any other way of playing video on a webpage. Here are some examples I could easily find on the inter-webs;

1. [HTML Canvas Video Player](https://stanko.github.io/html-canvas-video-player/)
2. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp)

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm from chrome on Android and it doesn't autoplay. In addition I already found it on the web.

Comment: @Kevin There is an auto-play attribute, But glad you found it already.

Comment: I know it, but, even with autoplay I cant make my videos autoplay on mobile browsers.

Comment: Then maybe look at using a javascript to trigger the play on page load.